# Examples of relations that don't satisfy one of the three properties of an equivalence relation while satisfying the other two?

Tags: solution-verification, recreational-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Just as a question that I have posed to myself: I want to find three relations $(S, \spadesuit)$, $(R, \clubsuit)$ and $(T, \blacksquare)$ for which $(S, \spadesuit)$ doesn't satisfy the reflexive property but satisfies symmetric and transitive. $(R, \clubsuit)$ doesn't satisfy the symmetric but satisfies the other two. Finally, $(T, \blacksquare)$ doesn't satisfy the transitive but satisfies the other two. Here my notation is that $S$, $R$, and $T$ are sets and $\spadesuit$, $\clubsuit$ and $\blacksquare$ are the relations. So far here is what I have come up with:

$$(S, \spadesuit)=(\mathbf{Z}, \text{x and y are even})$$ $$(R, \clubsuit)=(\mathbf{R},  x \leqslant y)$$ $$(T, \blacksquare )= ([x\, |\, x \text{ is a nonempty set} ] , x\cap y \neq \emptyset )$$

I guess I am asking for people to join me in the creativity here. Are there more interesting relations that satisfy these rules? I predict the question might be deemed inapropriate for the site. So here is a follow up question: I would love to find simple examples of equivalence relations that are *provable* at a very modest level. For example, I love the relation $x\sim y$ defined to be "$x-y$ is an integer" on the reals or the congruence of line segments. Are there other "easier" examples?

Comment: Apart from how things are presented here being nonstandard, this is all correct.  That being said, there are *infinitely many* examples of each... and most of them will be not easily represented.  If I were to add some examples however, I would suggest looking at some of the smallest examples as that can be illuminating.  You can find relations on the set $\{1,2,3\}$ for each type.

Comment: I did struggle with representing my idea. Can you point out what specificly is "non-standard" so I can improve?

Comment: I'm confused about use if x and y in the question. Are they defined somewhere? What is the scope where referring to x and y are allowed?

Comment: @EsaPulkkinen they are elements of the aforementioned defined set. e.g. $x$, $y \in \mathbf{R}$ in $(\mathbf{R}, x\leqslant y )$

Comment: Taking the first as an example, I would have called this "*The relation $\spadesuit$ over $\Bbb Z$ such that $x\spadesuit y \iff x$ and $y$ are both even.*"  Alternatively as "$\spadesuit = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb Z^2~:~x\equiv y\equiv 0\pmod{2}\}$" or similar.  As for your third, you need to be more careful as to what sort of sets you are considering as there is no such thing as a truly universal set in ZFC.  You could make it more formal by saying that we are considering $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$ or similar and specifying what universe we are pulling the sets from to consider.

Comment: As for minimal examples on $\{1,2,3\}$, Reflexive&Symmetric&notTransitive: $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$.  Reflexive&NotSymmetric&Transitive: $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2)\}$.  Finally NotReflexive&Symmetric&Transitive: $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

**Symmetric, transitive but not reflexive relation**

Consider on $\mathbb{R}$ the following relation:
$$x\sim y \iff x\cdot y>0$$
It's symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive because $0 \nsim 0 $.

**Reflexive, transitive but not symmetric relation**

Let $A$ and $B$ two sets, define the relation as follow:
$$A\sim B \iff A\subseteq B $$
This is clearly not symmetric as $A\subseteq B$ does not imply $B\subseteq A$.